# How to deal with malicious web requests

Tags: .net

In our .NET app we get requests for files like _vti_bin/owssvr.dll (which can be hack attempts).  I'd like to handle them by doing something like adding the following code to Application_BeginRequest:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("_vti_bin/owssvr.dll"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

But I figure this is an unscalable, ineffective way of handling the problem.  Any better ideas?

Comment: you should filter that on IIS or firewall, not application level

Comment: is this a question for serverfault.com?

Comment: The way he's trying to do it with ASP.NET definitely belongs here, but the right solution is probably serverfault.com material :)

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate the input.  I'll pursue this from a more server oriented perspective.  @Rubens - as always you're helpful.  If you put your comments in answers I'd vote them up - you've helped me on other questions too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this the sort of thing [URLScan](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/473/using-urlscan) is for?

URLScan is IIS extension from Microsoft that automatically rejects malicious requests before letting IIS handle them.  It rejects vti_bin requests and many other attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches that I've seen work in the past have been to place the following code as a default.aspx (making sure to set default.aspx as a Default Document type within IIS):

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>

<Head>
  <script language="CS" runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
    Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.End();
    } 
  </script>
</Head>
```

Another solution that I've seen work, is to create a custom HttpHandler with similar behaviour.  Then within the web.config define which paths to block.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just tell the webserver that _vti_bin is not web accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Nathan is right urlscan is the way to go -- also note this .NET will not see these requests unless you add *.dll to the extensions that .NET handles.  Otherwise, IIs will handle these requests.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your webserver doesn't have that security bug. If your server is immune to that exploit, it's pointless to block exploit attempts.